# What kind of data are sent in Westworld?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

In the tv series Westworld, Theresa Cullen and Charlotte Hale are sending data out of Westworld with the help of some re-programmed bots. This was discovered by Elsie Hughes.
When they were talking about it, they explicitly state that it is not about the programming code of the bots, but rather something more valuable.

**What kind of data are being sent out of Westworld? (And why are they so valuable?)**

Comment: I don't know the actual answer, but customer data - especially if that included details about the specific actions they took while in the park - would be extremely valuable to some people for its blackmail potential.

Comment: And season 2 has shown that it was a key to access customer data, but a lot more data then just some facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is specifically stated in the series but my take on this based on what I know :

Two things other than raw code could be interesting

- **The customers' information** (credits to *Anthony Grist*) would be dangerous to let out considering the kind of actions they take in Westworld (You don't want your boss learning that you raped a robot and murdered its entire "family")
- **The table from deep learning algorithm** (now this isn't confirmed that the androids learn from deep learning but it is safe to assume that it works roughly the same) which is the table that stores all the information that the androids learned in order to adapt and be "human". With that, someone could build androids without the hardest part of the code (Learning)